# PHP код все время инициализирует переменную заново и заново

Tags: javascript, php, html, wamp

Вот, в чем оно... Есть такой файл `index.php` и рядом файл `text.txt` запускаю через wamp, там есть код `<php? ... $i=23; /*и т.д.*/?>`  Далее нажимаю на кнопку `MyButton` и говорю `$i++;`.А следовательно переменная должна увеличиваться, т.е. `$i` должно быть ровно `24`, потом `25`, потом `26` и т.д., но этого не происходит переменная `$i` равна `24`.  Как мне инициализировать переменную `$i` только один раз? Такое чувство, что весь код `<php? Весь код?>` вызывается снова и снова. Не понимаю...
На экране всегда будет `Hello World! 24`. А мне надо:
`Hello World! $i`, где колеблется по правилу: `23<=$i<=888`;
Вот код, который и есть в файле index.php:

```
<?php

$i=23;
$myfile = fopen("text.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$number = fgets($myfile);//reading file
if (isset($_POST["number"])) {
   
    $i=$i+1;
    $number = "Hello, World! $i";
    $myfile = fopen("text.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $number);
    echo $number;
    //file_put_contents("line1.txt", ($_GET["number"]).PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
   
    return;
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var I;
        $(document).ready(function(){
    
           $('input:submit').click(function(e){
                I = "<?php echo $i?>";
                console.log(I);
              e.preventDefault();
              $.post(window.location, {'number': $("input#number").val()}, function(data) {
                 if(data) $("input#number").val(data); 
                 $('h1').html(data);
              });
              return false; // just in case if e.preventDefault() fails
           });

       });

        </script>
        <title>Add to text.txt: Hello World! $i</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <h1> <?= $number; ?></h1>
                
            <form method="POST">
                                            >
                <input type="hidden" id="number" name="number" value = "<?= $number; ?>">
                <input type="submit" value = "MyButton" id="next" name="next"  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А почему вы в тело $.post() передаете JSON, а затем пытаетесь его прочитать как form-data в $_POST? Если вам нужен JSON, то доставайте его из php://input, но используя dataType: "json", а если чисто массив в $_POST, то [массив](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) вида ["number" : 1]

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov Не знаю, как всё это работает... Могёте помочь? P.S. Код из нета. Мне важно сохранять все это дело в text.txt после каждого изменения $i?

Comment: Значение переменных не сохраняется между запросами. Т.е. строка `$i = 23;` будет выполняться каждый раз, как вы будите делать запрос к PHP. Если вам нужно сохранять состояние переменных между запросами, то вам необходимо рассмотреть использование cookies, сессий, хранилищ или передачи самого значения насквозь при повторном запросе.

Answer (score 2):

Вы просто-напросто никогда не передаете серверу переменную `$i` по нажатию на кнопку `myButton`. Соответственно сервер знает только ее начальное значение `23`. Все, что нужно это либо передавать серверу ее значение с формы, либо где-то сохранять увеличенное при каждом нажатии `myButton` значение переменной `$i` - например в файле или, что проще, в сессии. На примере сессии это будет так...

```php
session_start(); // <--- стартуем сессию
//$i=23; //<-- заменяем эту строчку на следующую, если конструкция Вам незнакома почитайте про тернарный оператор
$i = ( isset( $_SESSION['i'] ) ? intval( $_SESSION['i'] ) : 23 );
$myfile = fopen("text.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$number = fgets($myfile);//reading file
if (isset($_POST["number"])) {
   
    $i=$i+1;
    $_SESSION['i'] = $i; //<-- сохраняем новое значение переменной $i в сессию
    $number = "Hello, World! $i";
    $myfile = fopen("text.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $number);
    echo $number;
    //file_put_contents("line1.txt", ($_GET["number"]).PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
   
    return;
}
?>
```